# R - How do you set the default locale when installing packages

Tags: r, package

```
> install.packages("ISLR")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/ISLR_1.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2914144 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

tar: Failed to set default locale
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal write this

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

restart R

... or write this in R console

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

restart R